# How to render the same instance of an angular component in multiple places?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am wondering how you can render the same instance of an angular component in multiple places? For example: I am using this angular mat-stepper component. [mat-stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)
I need to make it so that I can render the same component in each the horizontal and vertical stepper but i need to have the same one. The reason for this is that in each one I have a form and I need the same instance of the form whether it is vertical or horizontal mode. If i just instantiate the same component in each horizontal/vertical mode then it maintains two instances in both horizontal/vertical. So if I update the form in one the changes dont go over to the other and vice versa. Any ideas how to solve that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a great article to help you out with what you are looking for by [Torsten Müller](https://medium.com/@diwadidu). It's a step in your direction in regards to displaying an instance in multiple ways without having to reload the page. With some tweaking you can get the data to update with the form and have it propagate across the horizontal and vertical instances since they are using the same data. Here is the [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-angular-viewchild-to-implement-multiple-visualizations-of-data-sets-b626689938f7)

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to use the same instance of components, but try to use some service to share states between components. `Service` could have `Subject` of your actual form values. And you should be `subscribed` to changes of your subject and update form values.

Comment: That was the approach that Im now leaning towards. I try to avoid those subscriptions when possible because in my experience then can create spaghetti havoc. I think i have to do that though thanks.

Comment: I do not know your problem but when your components forms are nested different solution is to pass your form values by @Input() and on form value change emit your values by output to your parent and then update nested child component. All your form values will be handled by parent component than you will not need service to share states.

Comment: The solution @Filip you mention is currently what is there. I am trying to change it so that the state is decoupled and can exist outside of the parent component ... I really don't like that pattern you mentioned :(